# Calculating the area bounded by 2 hyperbolas

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I have some trouble calculating the area bounded by two hyperbolas(in the first quadrant) in a analytical way.
The functions are:
$y=\sqrt{a^2+cx^2}$
$x=\sqrt{a^2+cy^2}$
I've tried hyperbolic substitutions, but it did not lead to an elegant solution.
My proposition is:
$\int_0^b \int^\sqrt{a^2+cy^2}_\sqrt{\frac{cy^2-a^2}{c}}dxdy$
In which $b=\sqrt{\frac{a^2+ca^2}{1-c^2}}$
I hope someone can point me in the right direction!
Picture of the problem:
(http://i65.tinypic.com/155qbr9.jpg)

Cheers

PS. a and c are constants and not equal to each other

Comment: If $a$ and $c$ are the same in the two equation the two hyperbolas has no common points.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to metion that $a$ and $c$ are constants and are not equal to each other.

Comment: If you know what a "Jacobian" is, then I suggest a change of variables, $u=a+cx^2$, $v=a+cy^2$.

Comment: I already tried this, it however did not ease the problem.

Comment: I understand that $a\ne c$ but if $a$ in the first equation is the same $a$ in the second equation and $c$ in the first equation is the same $c$ in the second equation than the two hyperbolas have the same asymptotes $y=\pm \sqrt{c}$ so they does not intersect.

Comment: Maybe a picture is more claryfing: see the link in the problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think making it a polar integral does the job.  The area in the first quadrant is symmetric, so it suffices to integrate from $0$ to $\pi/4$.  The curve is $x^2-cy^2 = a^2$, so we have $r^2\cos^2\theta - cr^2\sin^2\theta = a^2$.  The integral I get is

$${1\over 2}\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{a^2}{\cos^2\theta -c \sin^2\theta} \; d\theta={a^2\over 2}\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{1 -(c+1)\sin^2\theta} \; d\theta.$$

Now it's time to use the $t = \tan(\theta/2)$ substitution.  Multiply the final answer by 2 (or 8 if you want the area in your picture.)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Just for the record, $t=\tan \theta$ is less messy compared to $t = \tan \frac{\theta}{2}$...